# PHP MVC - How to get value of variable in include or require file

Tags: php

I'm learning and writting MVC by php. I set value of variable from file controller and i want to get value in file views but it's not working. 
My controller:

```
class BooksController extends Controller
    {
        function list()
        {
            $books = $this->model->get_all(); 
            render('view/book/list');
        }
    }
```

My views list.php:

```
 <?php
  var_dump($books);
?>
```

My function render:

```
function render($file_name,$extent="php"){
        $file_name = 'view/'.$file_name.'.'.$extent;
        if(!file_exists($file_name))
            throw new Exception("Can't open file ".$file_name);
        require_once $file_name; 
    }
```

Result: NULL

I trying replace:

```
render('view/book/list');//not work
```

to

```
require_once('view/book/list.php');//work
```

Pls tell me, What is wrong?

Comment: You need to pass the data - the `$books` variable in this case - to the `render()` function so that it is available in the scope of that function.

Comment: You only include the file in the scope of the function, so trying to access the variable inside the included file, outside the scope of the function is not going to work, since it will then be out of scope.

Comment: <?php var_dump($books); ?> I wrote it in list.php file.

Comment: Also your file path seems to be incorrect, refer to the answer by @Elenora Ivanova, but I still think the variable will be out of scope, unless you var_dump() it directly inside the function. Edit: according to your comment, saying that you do infact var_dump() the variable inside the include file, means that the file path seems to be your main issue.

Comment: @jeroen tks. I understood what you say. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing view/book/list.php to

```
$file_name = 'view/'.$file_name.'.'.$extent;
```

Which will result in $filename = 'view/view/book/list.php.php'

Dumping your variables on the screen or in a log file might help you in the future in situations like that. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Try

```
render('book/list');
```

Comment: Too bad your answer has just been invalidated by the OP's change :-) However, this could not have been the problem to begin with as the OP is throwing an exception if the file does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 times `view` when it goes in your function render and pass `$books` in your function `render` also.

```
class BooksController extends Controller
{
    function list()
    {
        $books = $this->model->get_all(); 
        render('book/list',$books);
    }
}
```

And in your function render

```
function render($file_name,$data,$extent="php"){
    $file_name = 'view/'.$file_name.'.'.$extent;
    $books = $data;
    if(!file_exists($file_name))
        throw new Exception("Can't open file ".$file_name);
    require_once $file_name; 
}
```